# Grafana azure SSO always logging in with Viewer role (default role)

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, grafana

I am using azure active directory for authentication and authorization of my grafana application.

I have followed the given tutorials present in : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/azuread/

I am starting my container with the following compose file :

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:9.4.7-ubuntu
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./grafana_config.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana

volumes:
  grafana-data:
```

The configuration file is as follows :

```
[auth.azuread]
name = Azure AD
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
auto_login = true
client_id = <redacted_client_id>
client_secret = <redacted_client_secret>
scopes = openid email profile
auth_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
token_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
allowed_domains =
allowed_groups = <admin_group_object_id> <editor_object_id>
role_attribute_strict = false
allow_assign_grafana_admin = true
skip_org_role_sync = true
[log]
level = "debug"
```

I am able to log in but even though I am member of all the security groups present in AD, I am still assigned `Viewer` while logging in .
I have tried adding

```
role_attribute_path = contains(info.roles[*], 'admin') && 'GrafanaAdmin' || contains(info.roles[*], 'editor') && 'Editor' || 'Viewer'
```

in my .ini file under `[auth.azuread]`.

`<admin_group_object_id>` are the `objectID` of the groups in AD assigned to the application as mentioned in the tutorial.

I tried getting the token but the token is not logged in the terminal neither sent to the application browser.

I believe the issue is `role_mapping` in the application (i.e. grafana app) side , but not sure how to map the `objectID` inside AD to grafana role in the application before starting the container.

What am I doing wrong ? Or is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

See linked [Azure auth doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/azuread/#map-roles):

> By default, Azure AD authentication will map users to organization roles based on the most privileged application role assigned to the user in AzureAD.

So you can't use `role_attribute_path` - it is not supported for this type of auth.

If you want to use `role_attribute_path` then use properly configured [generic OAuth](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/generic-oauth/). That Azure auth is just OAuth/OIDC, so there is no problem with basic auth.

Comment: I do not understand . I tried `role_attribute_path` as a workaround to map the AD groups to grafana roles. Do you mean this role mapping in azure AD SSO is not possbile?

Comment: @Echo read the doc. Is role_attribute_path mentioned in the Azure AD auth doc? NO -> you CAN'T use role_attribute_path with Azure AD auth. Is role_attribute_path mentioned in the generic OAuth doc? YES -> you CAN use role_attribute_path with generic OAuth.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I think I am misunderstanding your answer. The `role_attribute_path` is someting I just tried but do not intend to keep it. as far as I have understood the documentation `token_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token` should have authenticated me against the roles and groups I am part of. But I am not sure why do I still get viewer role even though I am part of Admin role.

Comment: Sorry, if it makes no sense. I am just working on it for the first time.